# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and inverse..

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

> If $F(x)$ is defined as $$F(x)= \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt$$   calculate $(F^{-1})'(y)$ in terms of $f$.

I have been working on this for a while now, does the aanswer to this incorporate the Inverse Function Theorem?

> $$(f^{-1})'(y_{0}))= \frac{1}{f'(x_{0})}$$ where $y_{0}=f(x_{0})$.

But I seem to have trouble adapting this theorem to integrals,  would this be correct $$(F^{-1})'(y) = \frac{1}{F'(x)}$$ where $y=F(x)$?? and so by fundamental theorem of calculus $$\frac{1}{F'(x)} = \frac{1}{f(x)}$$ any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Do you think we need to say something about existence of $F'(x) $?

Comment: Apologies, this is not the complete question ,I had to prove $F(x)$ was a bijection before hand and used the Inverse Function Theorem to show if F was differentiable everywhere then so is its inverse.... but is this solution correct?